# CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE is 32-bit instead of 64-bit in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

i'm newly join flutter development when open a new flutter project in android studio this error is showing on the logcat section. So what should i do right now?

```
A/linker: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/dpmd": "/system/lib64/libdpmframework.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

Comment: you do realise what is minimum system requirement for running flutter?? https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Comment: Yes i do, i install all the requirement which is needed

Comment: First requirement in that link is 64bit machine.. Do you have 64bit machine or 32bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

Based from the error thrown, `libdpmframework.so` seems to be built in a 32-bit process. It's likely that you're trying to create a build in 32-bit which causes the error. [Support for 32-bit](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html) on Android has been discontinued since mid-2019. I suggest using the default build settings for 64-bit going forward.